# How do I get a downloaded java file to work in an existing project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, download

For a school assignment I'm doing, we need to download and present our code to the TA to get it graded.  So, we just download the java file we turned in for the project.  This is giving me a problem though, and it probably has a very simple solution.. when I download the java file, and add it to the src file for the project (where all the .java files are stored), eclipse won't pull it up in the hierarchy on the left of the screen.  Also, when I try to run the main method, it pops up a window asking which Ant build to use.. I looked into what Ant builds are and don't really see how it applies to just running code.

So, how can I get this downloaded .java file to be recognized by the project, and eclipse?

Comment: Please post the said java code.

Comment: has nothing to do with the code, but I solved it.  Because like I said, it was turned in for a project, hopefully the code would've worked before I turned it in

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, and as I thought it is very simple.. For anyone who has this issue in the future, just rightclick the src file in eclipse for your project, and refresh it.  Refreshing the whole page by pressing F5 doesnt work, you need to refresh just the src file.

Comment: Actually you're not refreshing the source file. Rather, you're refreshing the sidebar "file explorer" bar. It is appearing in the hierarchy because you have refreshed said hierarchy.